# TypeError: concurrently(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to run a github program from https://github.com/StartBootstrap/sb-clean-blog-angular .
I faced this error when I run the command "npm start".

```
D:\Full-Stack-Development-Capstone\Frontend\sb-clean-blog-angular-1.2.0\scripts\start.js:14
}).then(success, failure);
   ^

TypeError: concurrently(...).then is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Full-Stack-Development-Capstone\Frontend\sb-clean-blog-angular-1.2.0\scripts\start.js:14:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1166:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:834:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Node.js v18.4.0
```

The script code

```
const concurrently = require('concurrently');
const port = process.env.PORT || 4200;

concurrently([
    { command: 'node scripts/pug-watch.js', name: 'PUG_WATCH', prefixColor: 'bgGreen.bold' },
    { 
        command: `npm run ng -- serve --port ${port} --open`,
        name: 'NG_SERVE', 
        prefixColor: 'bgBlue.bold',
    }
], {
    prefix: 'name',
    killOthers: ['failure', 'success'],
}).then(success, failure);

function success() {
    console.log('Success');    
}

function failure() {
    console.log('Failure');
}
```

Comment: The error is literally telling you what's wrong? `concurrently(...).then` is not a function. `concurrently([...]. {...})` does not return a promise. Read the API docs for that function, and update your code accordingly?

Comment: Hi Mike, how to fix it? i am not javascript trained.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently#concurrentlycommands-options) what you are using? Please go through the API usage

Comment: Hi Suraj seem like it, i'll take a look thank

Comment: The docs literally give this as the example and state that it returns a promise, did you actually read the docs yourself before writing your response?..

Answer (score 1):

Hi to fix this simply do this

```
const { result } = concurrently([
    { command: 'node scripts/pug-watch.js', name: 'PUG_WATCH', prefixColor: 'bgGreen.bold' },
    { 
        command: `npm run ng -- serve --port ${port} --open`,
        name: 'NG_SERVE', 
        prefixColor: 'bgBlue.bold',
    }
], {
    prefix: 'name',
    killOthers: ['failure', 'success'],
});

result.then(success, failure);
```

can read more on it here.
https://github.com/open-cli-tools/concurrently#api